# Fatal error in installing Quantlib-python

Tags: failed-installation, quantlib

I have built [QuantLib](http://www.quantlib.org/) using Visual C++ 2010 Express Edition after converting it from a version built under Visual C++ 2008 Epress Edition. My system is a 64 bit. 
I get the following error:

```
fatal error lnk1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
```

I am not good at programming and I read a lot of solutions from the web and tried them all but none of them worked for my case. Can you please help me to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you following the official instructions at http://www.quantlib.org/install.shtml?

Comment: Yeah. I followed those instructions. I built correctly QuantLib and I installed Boost and I set the directory as in the instructions but when I run the command setup.py build it says "module machine x86 conflicts with target machine 64 bit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a number of things, so I suggest you post to the QuantLib mailing list which is a more appropriate forum for going back and forth and diagnosing problems.

A couple of suggestions you might try in the meantime:

- there are unofficial binaries available for a few Python versions.  If you don't need to modify the library or the wrappers, try running

  ```
  pip install QuantLib-Python
  ```

  and see if that succeeds.  If it does, you're done.
- It could be that you compiled QuantLib as a 32-bit library and your Python is compiled as 64-bit instead.  Check that you have chosen the `x64` platform (in VC++2010, besides the menu that lets you choose "Release" or "Debug" configuration, there should be another that lets you choose "Win32" or "x64").

But as I said, it's better to move to the mailing list.